# Use literal operators (eg "and", "or") in Groovy expressions?

Tags: groovy, dsl

My current work project allows user-provided expressions to be evaluated in specific contexts, as a way for them to extend and influence the workflow. These expressions the usual logical ones f. To make it a bit palatable for non-programmers, I'd like to give them the option of using literal operators (e.g. and, or, not instead of &, |, !).

A simple search & replace is not sufficient, as the data might contains those words within quotes and building a parser, while doable, may not be the most elegant and efficient solution.

To make the question clear: is there a way in Groovy to allow the users to write

```
x > 10 and y = 20 or not z
```

but have Groovy evaluate it as if it were:

```
x > 10 && y == 20 || !z
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're going to need to write your own parser

Comment: By `&` and `|` you mean `&&` and `||`? Or you really mean the bitwise operators?

Comment: @WillP My bad, I meant the logical ones. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of Groovy support [Command chains](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#_command_chains), so it's indeed possible to write this:

```
compute x > 10 and y == 20 or not(z)
```

The word "compute" here is arbitrary, but it cannot be omitted, because it's the first "verb" in the command chain. Everything that follows alternates between verb and noun:

```
 compute  x > 10  and  y == 20  or   not(z)
 ───┬───  ──┬───  ─┬─  ───┬───  ─┬─  ──┬───
   verb    noun   verb   noun   verb  noun
```

A command chain is compiled like this:

```
verb(noun).verb(noun).verb(noun)...
```

so the example above is compiled to:

```
compute(x > 10).and(y == 20).or(not(z))
```

There are many ways to implement this. Here is just a quick & dirty proof of concept, that doesn't implement operator precedence, among other things:

```
class Compute {
    private value
    Compute(boolean v) { value = v }
    def or (boolean w) { value = value || w; this }
    def and(boolean w) { value = value && w; this }
    String  toString() { value }
}

def compute(v) { new Compute(v) }
def not(boolean v) { !v }
```

You can use command chains by themselves (as top-level statements) or to the right-hand side of an assignment operator (local variable or property assignment), but not inside other expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can swap operators like `>` and `=` for the facelets-like `gt` and `eq`, respectively, i THINK your case may be doable, though it will require a lot of effort:

```
x gt 10 and y eq 20 or not z
```

resolves to:

```
x(gt).10(and).y(eq).20(or).not(z)
```

And this will be hell to parse.

The way @Brian Henry suggested is the easiest way, though not user-friendly, since it needs the parens and dots.

Well, considering we can swap the operators, you could try to intercept the `Integer.call` to start expressions. Having the missing properties in a script being resolved to operations can solve your new keywords problem. Then you can build expressions and save them to a list, executing them in the end of the script. It's not finished, but i came along with this:

```
// the operators that can be used in the script
enum Operation { eq, and, gt, not }

// every unresolved variable here will try to be resolved as an Operation
def propertyMissing(String property) { Operation.find { it.name() == property} }

// a class to contain what should be executed in the end of the script
@groovy.transform.ToString 
class Instruction { def left; Operation operation; def right }

// a class to handle the next allowed tokens
class Expression {
  Closure handler; Instruction instruction
  def methodMissing(String method, args) {
    println "method=$method, args=$args"
    handler method, args
  }
}

// a list to contain the instructions that will need to be parsed
def instructions = []

// the start of the whole mess: an integer will get this called
Integer.metaClass {
  call = { Operation op ->
    instruction = new Instruction(operation: op, left: delegate)
    instructions << instruction
    new Expression(
      instruction: instruction,
      handler:{ String method, args -> 
        instruction.right = method.toInteger()
        println instructions
        this
      })
  }
}

x = 12
y = 19
z = false

x gt 10 and y eq 20 or not z
```

Which will give an exception, due the `not()` part not being implemented, but it can build two Instruction objects before failing:

```
[Instruction(12, gt, 10), Instruction(19, eq, 20)]
```

Not sure if it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks Will, it's indeed too much work for this particular case

Answer (score 0):

The [GDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Boolean.html) tacks on `and()` and `or()` methods to Boolean.  If you supplied a method like

```
Boolean not(Boolean b) {return !b}
```

you could write something like

```
(x > 10).and(y == 20).or(not(4 == 1))
```

I'm not sure that's particularly easy to write, though.

Comment: Thanks, but indeed, it wouldn't be easier at all.