# Binding 'and' to &&

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to build a Groovy DSL that binds `and` to `&&`:

```
def binding = new Binding([
    and: &&
])

def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
println shell.evaluate '''
        true and false
    '''
}
```

However I'm getting a compile-time error:

```
>groovyc AndOr.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
AndOr.groovy: 2: unexpected token: && @ line 2, column 7.
        and: &&
         ^

1 error
```

How can I bind `"and"` to the `&&` operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13778737/6509

Answer (score 0):

Groovy parses `left operand right` as `left(operand).getRight()`. Turning `and` into `&&` operator is parser related, and I doubt you will be able to do it without tweaking groovy source code, antlr, etc.

---

To get your snippet working, this code intercepts `Boolean::call` with metaprogramming, creating a new `EBoolean` object. Then it uses a `getProperty` method to intercept `getRight()` part:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

class EBoolean {
    Boolean left
    Op op
    def getProperty(String property) {
        def right = Boolean.parseBoolean(property)
        op == Op.AND ? left && right : null
    }
}

class Meta {
    { 
        Boolean.metaClass.call { Op op ->
            new EBoolean(left: delegate, op: op)
        }
    }
}

enum Op { AND }

binding = new Binding([ and: Op.AND ])

def compilerConfig = new CompilerConfiguration( scriptBaseClass: DelegatingScript.class.name)

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, binding, compilerConfig)
script = shell.parse( '''
        true and false
    ''' )

script.setDelegate new Meta()

assert script.run() == false
```

It works, but it's pretty specific, and hard to use generically. It won't work if you want to get another variable name from the context, like `a=false; true and a`. Binding won't help much, as it doesn't work with variables declared with `def` inside scripts:

Comment: How hacky is it to replace `and` with `&&` **before** evaluating the script, and then run it? So if a user wrote `true and false`, that'd be pre-processed to `true && false`, and then we'd evaluate that.

Comment: Very hacky. It might replace undesired content, like strings, variable names and other code

Comment: No doubt it's hacky. If I replaced all " and "'s (note the leading and trailing whitespace) with " && ", then it *may* work, no? However, there's a risk if " and " is used as a variable, I think?

Comment: Yep, it may work, but it still could change strings and comments, if the user supplied any.

Comment: Since `method1 arg1 method2 arg2` equals `method1(arg1).method2(arg2)`, I started to look at `trueFn = { -> true }` and then: `def binding = new Binding([
 TRUE: tFn, FALSE: fFn()])`. Then, evaluating `TRUE and FALSE` worked. However, passing `{ -> true }` rather than `true`, i.e. the former expression **applied**, are not interchangeable. In other words, `true` or `false` can show up on the left **or** right-hand side. gist - https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/00eab813e0e722cbffcb

Comment: I like that. You may also want to take a look at [Scala implicit conversion](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/implicit-conversions-in-scala.html), since it resolves `left op right` as `left.op(right)`.

Comment: Thanks, Will P. However, per the fact that `TRUE` or `FALSE` could appear on either side, my attempted solution doesn't work, right?

Comment: yeah, you will always bump on groovy's parsing order. If you could do something like `let true and false`, that'd be great. Having an even number of statements really makes everything easier. The key point is: `AND` should be a method, and not a parameter. Whereas `false` and `true` must be objects inside your script